# scrollTo top scrolls past top due to edgesIgnoringSafeArea

Tags: swiftui

I need to be able to `scrollTo` the top of a view, which I've set up. However, due to `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`, it's scrolling past the top of the view slightly (equal to the height of the safe area).

If I remove `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`, it scrolls to the top of the view properly.

How can I modify my code so that I can use both `scrollTo` and `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`?

```
struct MyPageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        // more code in here
                    }
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .onChange(of: environmentVariables.scrollPosition) {
                    if let target = environmentVariables.scrollPosition {
                        withAnimation {
                            value.scrollTo(target, anchor: .top)
                        }
                        
                        environmentVariables.scrollPosition = nil
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` in the first place? Please explain more about the context.

Comment: @Sweeper I use it because I want an `Image` (which sits inside the `VStack`) to  touch the top of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a different `anchor` for scrolling.

The anchor can be supplied as a `UnitPoint`, so to see if it works, you could start by trying something like:

```swift
value.scrollTo(target, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.1))
```

If it does work and you would like to scroll to the top of the main display more precisely, you will need to compute the fraction of the display occupied by the top insets. This can be done by surrounding the `NavigationStack` with a `GeometryReader`:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { outer in
        let safeAreaInsets = outer.safeAreaInsets
        let screenHeight = outer.size.height + safeAreaInsets.top + safeAreaInsets.bottom
        let yTop = safeAreaInsets.top / max(1, screenHeight)
        NavigationStack {

            // other content as before, apart from:
            value.scrollTo(target, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: yTop))

        }
    }
}
```

I gave it a try using a simplified version of your view. I found that it does indeed work, but it was still scrolling into the safe area by a little. It works better if `yTop` is computed using just the height of the `GeometryReader`, instead of the overall height of the screen:

```swift
struct MyPageView: View {

    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .yellow, .orange, .green, .teal, .blue, .indigo, .purple]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outer in
            let safeAreaInsets = outer.safeAreaInsets
//            let screenHeight = outer.size.height + safeAreaInsets.top + safeAreaInsets.bottom
            let yTop = safeAreaInsets.top / max(1, outer.size.height)
            NavigationStack {
                ScrollViewReader { value in
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                                color
                                    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                                    .id(color)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        withAnimation {
                                            value.scrollTo(color, anchor: UnitPoint(x: 0.5, y: yTop))
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]